# Cannot add new products when manually creating a new order

Tags: opencart

I have been searching for days all over the internet for a solution and yet nothing found ! It is very weird their is no solution, workaround or a fix for such very important feature in Opencart system.

I am on OpenCart 3.0.3.6 and all what I am trying to do is create an order from admin side on behalf of a customer... this is a must for my store as we take order by phone.

Steps:

1. Go to: Admin > Orders > Insert (+)
2. Choose a customer, then click continue.
3. Choose any product and click on " +Add Product"
4. The products are not being added on to the table even if repeated the same step 1000 times and the weird is that there are no errors are being logged, no error are displayed on the screen and even the Google Chrome inspector logged no errors under console tab.

**The only error I could find is the below:**

_ In Firefox Inspector under "Console" tab.

```
Cookie “__cfduid” will be soon treated as cross-site cookie against “https://examle.com/admin/index.php?route=catalog/product/autocomplete&user_token=kjkjsdsakdakjsdjashdasdas&filter_name=” because the scheme does not match. index.php
Cookie “__cfduid” will be soon treated as cross-site cookie against “https://example.com/index.php?route=api/cart/add&api_token=kjkjsdsakdakjsdjashdasdas&store_id=0” because the scheme does not match. index.php
Cookie “__cfduid” will be soon treated as cross-site cookie against “https://example.com/index.php?route=api/cart/products&api_token=kjkjsdsakdakjsdjashdasdas&store_id=0” because the scheme does not match.
```

What should I do ? is there a fix somewhere ? a patch ? code modifications ?

Thank you,

Comment: There might be a mod or extension that's breaking something in the background (e.g. one that modifies products or does something when products are added to the cart). Have a look at the error log and see what it says there ("System" > "Maintenance" > "Error Logs").

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solved !

After days of searching, finally the problem has been solved and was due to caching.

Neither Cloudflare caching, nor website caching but the problem was from cPanel server caching where it could be turned off from: cPanel > Cache Manager > Select your site > Under Options tab > Turn Off Caching for this site.

Voila the problem is now gone for good !